# Shouldn't Documentation privileges be removed?

Tags: bug, documentation, privileges

[In the list of privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), there are still Documentation privileges (namely [Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-voting), [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-commenting) and [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing)).

Since Documentation is pretty much closed, shouldn't those be removed as well?

Answer (score 3):

They'll likely be removed in due course, but in reality, having them now isn't hurting anything.  You can't access any pages related to Documentation that would give you any platform to apply these privileges *anyway*.

Think of it like you being able to cook on your grandparent's gas stove for the first time, but they went to the store to get the groceries and took *all* the matches with them.  Yes, you technically have the power, but absolutely no means.